# Python psycopg2 Postgres :- How to insert timestamp without time zone to a timestamptz field in postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have 2 tables **tabl1** and **tabl2** in postgres database , DDLS of which are attached below:-

```
create table tabl1(col1 int, col2 timestamp);
create table tabl2(col1 int, col2 timestamptz);
```

In the first table tabl1, I have a record as below.

```
insert into tabl1(col1, col2) select 1, '2019-08-26 14:38:33';
```

I want to insert the data from tabl1 to tabl2 and I can do it simply by using psycopg2 package in python and issuing an execute from tabl1 to tabl2.

```
import psycopg2

host = '*****************'
port = '****'
dbname = '*****'
user = '*****'
password = '*****'

try:
    db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host,
                               port=port,
                               dbname=dbname,
                               user=user,
                               password=password)
    db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    db_cursor.execute("""
                    BEGIN;
                    insert into tabl2 (
                    col1,
                    col2)
                    SELECT
                    col1,
                    col2 from tabl1;
                    COMMIT;""")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as e:
    raise
finally:
    print("done!!")
```

Now the problem is coming here,

The timestamp is converted to 2019-08-27 03:08:33 in **tabl2** (may be because the col2 in tabl2 is timestamptz and not timestamp).

Since I cannot change the table DDL, I am looking for ways to avoid getting the timestamp casted to timestamp with time zone . so that I can retain the same value '2019-08-26 14:38:33' in **tabl2**.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

**Please Note:-** The same query when executed in Postgres Database directly, works just fine.

Comment: In `psql` what does `show timezone` return? Are you running the `psycopg2` code on the same machine as the Postgres server? Where are you seeing the value `2019-08-27 03:08:33`, in `psql` in the table or somewhere else? If you are using `timestamptz` then time zone casting will take place.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver for looking into this. The "show time zone" returns Asia/Calcutta.
And psycopg2 is running on a different server.

Comment: Please read entire comment. And the server where the `psycopg2` code is running is using what time zone? and where are you reading `2019-08-27 03:08:33`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am thankful to you for highlighting the correct behavior of timestamptz, I think I created confusion here  and it was a flaw in my understanding the behavior of timestamptz.I checked the timestamp in both the tables using psql (in the same server), the timestamp is same 2019-08-26 14:38:33.942, However since the client with which I was checking the timestamp earlier was running on my local machine (i.e. different time zone), so it was converted to local time before being displayed.
My understanding may still be incorrect , so please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes it will be converted. Read [Timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps